# NSURLSessionUploadTask does not respond to resume ios8 Beta3 (Device only)

Tags: ios8, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask, aws-sdk-ios

When sending the `resume` method on a `NSURLSessionUploadTask` using a background client, `NSURLSessionConfiguration:backgroundSessionConfiguration:`, the process never begins. I can not reproduce on simulator, only on the device, and only on 8.0.

This is not an issue regarding discretionary background tasks, `resume` is ran in the foreground and literally, nothing happens. No delegation callbacks, no progress, no crashes, no network activity, nothing.

I filed radar:://17703428

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, but on iOS 7.1.2, and only with a backgroundSessionConfiguration. I'm uploading a file to S3.

Comment: Met exactly the same issue and couldnt do anything except banging my head on the table

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on an iPad with iOS 7.1.2. Then I restarted the device, and it started working. It seems it is possible for whatever process Apple is using to handle these uploads to get messed up.